# RequestProductPurchaseAsync and transaction failures

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases for a Windows Phone 8 app. The docs for `RequestProductPurchaseAsync` don't exist specifically for the phone. In the Windows Store docs, there's a funny line:

> You should treat a success result as indicating the async process
>   completed without errors. To ensure that the transaction itself was
>   successful, check the LicenseInformation element in the returned
>   receipt.

There's no `LicenseInformation` element (or attribute) in the receipt. There's `Receipt`, `ProductReceipt`, and `Signature`. Question - did anyone work with in-app purchases before? How is transaction failure/cancellation reported?

Comment: I am wondering about this too

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but isn't there anything you can use in the XML returned (AppReceipt or ProductReceipt elements)? Looks like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967814.aspx isn't the most helpful page on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my hands on a real phone.

Cancellation is reported by an async completion (parameters `Info`, `Status`) with Status=AsyncStatus.Error, Info.ErrorCode is COMException with HResult=0x80004005 (E_FAIL).

For at least some of the genuine transaction failures (e. g. product ID not found in the catalog), the reported status and HRESULT are the same. I don't think there's a good way to catch a cancellation with the current API. Reporting `AsyncStatus.Canceled` would be a good idea, but so far it's not implemented.